# <fieldset hides when page re-loads - MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

EDIT:
Here is the exact problem that I have demonstrate, please have a look and as soon as I click the submit button it post back and lost its state and as you can see in the sample code I have three pages I'm posting the form
1) EmployeeForm, 2) EmployerForm, 3) ContractorForm

https://dotnetfiddle.net/wVtwgW

How do I persist the checkbox?

Once I post the page and it reloads the same page if I have my data-model invalid and it display the error message on the screen but the problem is that, it hides the `fieldset` and the user has to click the checkbox again to show the `fieldset`.

my question is: how can I still show the `fieldset` and show the error message in it?

//my scripts that shows the fieldset

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#Employee').change(function() {
            if (this.checked) { 
                $('#emp').show();
            }  
        });
 });
</script>
```

//it shows the fieldset with checkbox:

```
<fieldset class="fieldset-auto-width">
    <legend>
        Select Employee
    </legend>
    <table width="auto">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Employee
            </th>
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBox("Employee")
            </td>
        </tr> 
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

//my form where I have all the input text and button etc...

```
<fieldset id="emp" style="display: none" class="fieldset-auto-width">
    <legend>
        Employee Display
    </legend>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("EmployeeServer", "EmployeeForm", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div>..... </div>

    }

</fieldset>
```

Comment: Have you considered to post with `ajax`? It will maintain your page's state. Otherwise you could store variables in the viewmodel or even session variable. But that's ugly.

Comment: is Employee part of your model?

Comment: yes it is part of model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using @Html.CheckBox() use @Html.CheckBoxFor()

```
<td>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Employee)
</td>
```

this will retain the state of the checkbox when you return the model state errors..

in your javascript, just call the $("#Employee") change event after the page loads..

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#Employee').change(function() {
        if (this.checked) { 
            $('#emp').show();
        }  
    });

    $('#Employee').trigger("change");
 });
```

Set the Fieldset display value when view is rendered

```
<fieldset id="emp" style="@(Model.Employee ? "": "display: none")" class="fieldset-auto-width">
    <legend>
        Employee Display
    </legend>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("EmployeeServer", "EmployeeForm", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div>..... </div>

    }

</fieldset>
```

this will hide the fieldset if Model.Employee = false or display it if Model.Employee = true.

Comment: what is the `$('#Employee').trigger("change");` for?

Comment: it will fire the change event every time the page loads.. so if the value of Employee is equal to true, this will cause the `$('#emp').show();` to execute

Comment: down the road i might have more then one checkbox so in that case i will end-up having multiple lines of `trigger("change")`

Comment: or you can set the display property of the Fieldset based on the model value

Comment: style="@(Model.Employee ? "", "display:none")"

Comment: after implementing the above logic and now i have seen that when the page loads and when i click on the checkbox it does not show `fieldset` and i have that .trigger("change")

Comment: other question i have is, how do you update checkbox status in the model from jquery?

Comment: `$('#Employee').prop('checked', true); //checked  or false to uncheck`

Comment: just realized you dont even have the Employee checkbox inside your form tag so that value never gets posted back

Comment: so inside `@using` statement I have did something like this `@Model.Employee = true` but getting error seems razor does not like that

Comment: I will update you and the only challenging I am facing is, I have three checkbox 1) employee 2) employer 3) contractor so each checkbox render a different field set or div and each has its own form  begin-form, I will update my question

Comment: I have updated my question and also I have demonstrate the problem I'm facing here, please have a look https://dotnetfiddle.net/wVtwgW

Answer (score 1):

Just do it with JavaScript. Look for the rendered element from the validation summary helper, and if it exists then you can show your employee form. You can add it to your already executing script like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#Employee').change(function() {
        if (this.checked) { 
            $('#emp').show();
        }  
    });

    //check for validation summary elements
    if($('.validation-summary-errors').length > 0){
        //and show previous entry if present
        $('#emp').show();
    }
});
```